# How can i interact with cloud to store/retrieve the data?

Tags: android, cloud, persistence

The application I am currently developing needs to store/retrieve data using a database in the Cloud. But I do not know how to write code to communicate with such database.

The data I am going to store in the database is like paragraph.

Comment: Please provide more info about your problem. eg. what cloud storage you are going to use.

Comment: Use Parse, Firebase Databases, it will help you!

Comment: You are not being specific. You need to do some research into what type of cloud storage you want to use. Storing info in AWS compared to info storage on mongolab is a totally different story. Plus there are plenty of tutorials out there on this subject which depends on the storage solution you choose.